# MapKit - Overlay image where 1 pixel = x square feet

Tags: mapkit, overlay

I have a 256x256 image that I would like to place on a map via an overlay.  I would like to know how to scale the image so that 1 pixel of the image represents "x" square feet on the map (where "x" is some arbitrary number I determine at runtime).

Comment: how do you place the image on the map in the first place?